# Log4Net Error:File based login in log4net not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, logging, log4net

i am trying to implement log4net logger to my WPF application.file based login not working for me.

I've read a lot of other questions and answers, but I haven't been able to fix it yet... and this is the error I get:

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <configSections> elements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

**log4net.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="console" />
      <appender-ref ref="file" />      
    </root>
    <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="${LocalAppData}//myapp//Logs//myappplog.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>  
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

**Assemblyinfo.cs**

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net configSource="log4net.config" />
  <entityFramework>
```

**mainview.xaml.cs**
public partial class MainView : UserControl
{

```
   private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Getloaded();
    }
    public void Getloaded()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        try
        {
            log.Info("        =============  Started Application  =============        ");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the `log4net` but not adding it. It causes .net to rise that error.
You should ether remove `log4net` section declaration from the config file and pass your configuration file name (log4net.config) into the `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure("log4net.config");` method or add log4net configuration section into the App.config directly (`<log4net configSource="log4net.config" />`.
I believe that the second way will be best for you.

Here is how the config will look like in this case.

```
<configSections>
     <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />     
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<log4net configSource="log4net.config" />
...
```

Comment: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure("log4net.config"); this shows and error says that  ""cannot convert from 'string' to 'log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository'""

Comment: <section  name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler" Source="log4net.config" />  this also showing error

Comment: @developer I've updated answer with more details. I strongly suggest to check the documentation on app configuration. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/section-element here is the link.

Comment: @ Vyacheslav Benedichuk i have updated the code and still showing the same error

Comment: @developer how your updated config file looks like?

Comment: @ Vyacheslav Benedichuk i have updated my question with mentioned change

Comment: @developer could you please make sure that log4net.config is copied to your bin folder? If it is - remove the `<configuration>` tag from it.